# What causes this beamer block to be slightly offset to the right?

Tags: beamer, horizontal-alignment, block

I'm facing a problem with the `block` environment in `beamer`. Adding a `tikzpicture` seems to offset the following block slightly to the right. What is causing that behaviour and how can I prevent it?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Berlin}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

% as expected

\begin{frame}{Test}
\begin{block}{centered}
Test
\end{block}

\centering

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [] (box){%
    dsdsadsad
};
\end{tikzpicture}%

\begin{block}{not properly centered}
Test
\end{block}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe not an answer, but putting the tikz picture in a centred environment solves the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `\centering` declaration, not the `\tikzpicture` environment, is to blame for this undesirable horizontal offset you report; if you comment the `tikzpicture` out but leave `\centering` in, your second block gets gets offset to the right as well.

**Edit**: see [percusse's comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/164547/what-causes-this-beamer-block-to-be-slightly-offset-to-the-right/164552#comment377734_164552) and disregard my earlier divagations. Simply use a `center` environment instead of an unscoped `\centering` (which messes things up), here.

[image: screenshot of output]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Berlin}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Smoking the culprit (\texttt{\string\centering}) out\ldots}
\begin{block}{centered}
Test
\end{block}

\centering           %<---- this causes the horizontal offset...

%\begin{tikzpicture} %<--- not the tikzpicture
%\node [] (box){%
%    dsdsadsad
%};
%\end{tikzpicture}%

\begin{block}{not properly centered}
Test
\end{block}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Using a \texttt{center} environment instead}
\begin{block}{centered}
  Test
\end{block}

\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [] (box){%
        dsdsadsad
    };
    \end{tikzpicture}%
\end{center}

\begin{block}{not properly centered}
  Test
\end{block}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. I learned that \centering is better than the center environment because the center environment includes additional white space. See ftp://ftp.dante.de/tex-archive/info/l2tabu/english/l2tabuen.pdf (Section 3.1). Ahhh... I see there is a difference between the center and centering environment.

Comment: @ManuelKuehner The `\centering` macro is appropriate in many cases, but in `beamer`, if you need to center something horizontally, a `centering` environment seems preferable to both `\centering` or a `center` environment.

Comment: @ManuelKuehner Why are you centering? The blocks are centered by default.

Comment: @percusse I think Manuel wants to center the `tikzpicture`. I've just realised that `centering` doesn't do that...

Comment: Aah, OK sorry. I have a headerless and transparent block for such stuff. It keeps things scoped automatically and might be a safer approach than leaving `\centering` unscoped

Comment: @percusse You're right. I've updated my answer.