# Beamer: Imitating a beamer block - problem with the width

Tags: beamer

This is a follow up on my last [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/164547/what-causes-this-beamer-block-to-be-slightly-offset-to-the-right). I want a text block with (text width and outer shape) the **same width** as a beamer block but it doesn't work. The default definitioin of a beamer block is [here](http://www.tex.ac.uk/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/base/themes/inner/beamerinnerthemedefault.sty). They use something like `\begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep*=.75ex]{block title}`. But if I use this the box is not properly centered anymore.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Berlin}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

% as expected

\begin{frame}{Test}

\begin{block}{Test}
Test
\end{block}

\tikzstyle{myBox} = [draw=none, fill=green,
    rectangle,inner sep=10pt,align=left,minimum width=\textwidth,text width=0.8\textwidth]

\begin{centering}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [myBox]{dsdsadsad kdjskdj sdksdk sdks dksjkdj skdjksdjksjdksjdksjdksjdksa fjdjf dkfjdkfjdkfj kdjfkdfjkdsjfkdjf};
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{centering}

%
\begin{block}{Test}
Test
\end{block}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

> My aim is to imitate the lower part of the beamer block. I use a tikz picture because I want to change transparency and other stuff.

**I would like to avoid using additional packages. Is there a way to do it with TikZ? Maybe a beamercolorbox?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the new tcolorbox inner theme (https://www.ctan.org/pkg/beamertheme-tcolorbox ). One of the features of this theme is that tcolorbloxes will have the same look and feel (width, sharp/round corners, shadows) as normal beamer blocks.

It will normally also use the same colours as beamer blocks, but you can overwrite this if you prefer the lovely green :)

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Berlin}

\useinnertheme{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

% as expected

\begin{frame}{Test}

\begin{block}{Test}
Test
\end{block}


\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=green]
dsdsadsad kdjskdj sdksdk sdks dksjkdj skdjksdjksjdksjdksjdksjdksa fjdjf dkfjdkfjdkfj kdjfkdfjkdsjfkdjf
\end{tcolorbox}%


%
\begin{block}{Test}
Test
\end{block}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for this new solution and it's nice to see you again being active here

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner You're welcome!

Answer (score 6):

Next fragment is copied from `beameruserguide`:

[image]

This means that colored boxes are wider than `\textwidth`. Therefore, when you uses `\textwidth` inside `TikZ` box declaration, you are fixing its total width, not its exterior one.

If you want to use special boxes inside `beamer` I'd suggest using [`tcolorbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox). A possible solution for your example looks like

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Berlin}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[skins,breakable]{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Test}

\begin{block}{Test}
dsdsadsad kdjskdj sdksdk sdks dksjkdj skdjksdjksjdksjdksjdksjdksa fjdjf dkfjdkfjdkfj kdjfkdfjkdsjfkdjf
\end{block}

\begin{centering}
\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced, arc = 0pt, frame hidden, left=1pt, right=1pt, oversize, colback=green]
dsdsadsad kdjskdj sdksdk sdks dksjkdj skdjksdjksjdksjdksjdksjdksa fjdjf dkfjdkfjdkfj kdjfkdfjkdsjfkdjf
\end{tcolorbox}%
\end{centering}

%
\begin{block}{Test}
Test
\end{block}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! How did you figure out the exact values for the width you need? I was hoping to be able to use TikZ because I want to use the opactiy key (transparency). Is this supported by tcolorbox?

Comment: @ManuelKuehner: The values were obtained by trial and error. I couldn't find to many information about used enlargement for colourful blocks. And when found it didn't worked as expected. `tcolorbox` is based on `TiKZ` and supports transparencies, shadows, figures in background, etc. Take a look at its [documentation](http://texdoc.net/pkg/tcolorbox).

Comment: I added a request because I do not want to an additional package if possible. If there is no way then I will accept the answer.

Comment: @ManuelKuehner: `beamercolorbox` environment is defined in `beamerbasecolor.tex`. If you look there will see how this kind of boxes also adjust margins around them. This code is not enough easy for me to understand it completely and help you to solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks - I understand. The same applies for me :). Maybe someone has an idea.

Answer (score 4):

Here is two solutions using TikZ and using the fact that a `block` uses an horizontal extra margin of `.75ex` on each side.

## 1st solution

Here, I enlarge the text width via a `columns` environment then I insert your `tikzpicture` using `\textwidth`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Berlin}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
% First solution
\tikzset{myBox/.style={draw=none,fill=green,rectangle,inner sep=10pt,
    align=left,minimum width=\textwidth,text width=0.8\textwidth}}
\begin{frame}{Test}
  \begin{block}{Test}
    Test
  \end{block}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\myw{\textwidth+1.5ex}
  \begin{columns}
    \column{\myw pt}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \node [myBox]{dsdsadsad kdjskdj sdksdk sdks dksjkdj
        skdjksdjksjdksjdksjdksjdksa fjdjf dkfjdkfjdkfj
        kdjfkdfjkdsjfkdjf};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
  \end{columns}
  \begin{block}{Test}
    Test
  \end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Berlin}
\usepackage{tikz}
```

## 2nd solution

Here, I use `trim left` and `trim right` to enlarge the `tikzpicture` beyond `\textwidth` and I anchor the `node` on the `west`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Berlin}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
% Second solution
\tikzset{
  myPict/.style={trim left=.75ex,trim right=.75ex},
  myBox2/.style={line width=0,anchor=west,draw=none,fill=green,
    rectangle,inner sep=10pt,align=left,minimum width=\textwidth+1.5ex,
    text width=0.8*(\textwidth+1.5ex)},
}
\begin{frame}{Test2}
  \begin{block}{Test2}
    Test2
  \end{block}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[myPict]
    \node [myBox2] {dsdsadsad kdjskdj sdksdk sdks dksjkdj
      skdjksdjksjdksjdksjdksjdksa fjdjf dkfjdkfjdkfj kdjfkdfjkdsjfkdjf};
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \begin{block}{Test2}
    Test2
  \end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```